# Delphi 2007 on Windows 7 closes debugger opens

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007

I installed Delphi 2007 on a Windows 7 system.  When I click on the Run button I see the debugger screen open and then the entire application (Delphi) closes.  I have tried running two programs, one being a simple single-button-with-message type of test program.

- I can successfully compile the program in 2007.
- I also have XE2 installed on the same machine and it runs properly.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled.  After the reinstall I tested without reloading any of the 3rd party products.
- The same computer runs 2007 and XE2 under Windows XP (dual boot configuration)

My searches have not turned up any similar symptoms.  I need ideas on how to diagnose further or a possible workaround.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you install Delphi 2007 **after** installing XE? If so, you've made a mistake. You should always install multiple versions of Delphi in the order of their release (eg., D2007, D2009, D2010, XE, XE2). If you installed D2007 last, you've probably corrupted it (and your other installations as well).

Comment: @KenWhite just curious but it because older versions delete some files of the newer version if the release order is not followed?

Comment: No, it's because earlier versions do things differently than later versions. Think about it; Delphi XE sets up the PATH and other environmental stuff (and does it knowing earlier versions of Delphi might be there); Delphi 2007 doesn't know XE could be there (because it didn't exist), so it does things that were proper 5 years ago but might not be now. So now, things are set up for D2007. Where does XE find things?

Comment: I routinely install delphi versions out of order and have no problems. PATH is not problem that I am aware of. You can remove all Delphi entries from PATH quite happily.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a x64 version of Windows 7? 
If yes, you need the hotfix.

It is already explained here:
[Delphi issues on windows 7 x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448785/delphi-issues-on-windows-7-x64)